# how to sum up array resulting from a calculated value(such as grand total from subtotals) in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

i was wondering this is a very basic and probably stupid question. i am sorry for that.
how do i sum up the values of a calculated array. i want to get the sum of sub totals as grand total in php. following is the code

```
if(count($_POST))
{
$len = count($_POST['item']);

    for ($i=0; $i < $len; $i++)
    {           
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo $_POST['item'][$i] . '<br>';
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $_POST['qty'][$i] . '<br>';
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $_POST['price'][$i] . '<br>';
        echo "</td><td>";
        $tv = ($_POST['qty'][$i]*$_POST['price'][$i]);
        echo $tv;
        echo "</td></tr>";      
    }
}
                echo "</table>";
```

I am receiving Item,Quantity,Price from the previous form (variable no of rows)
now i have been able to calculate and echo out the sub totals($tv). but facing problems in calculating the grand total.
grand total = sum of all $tv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sum  = 0;    
for ($i=0; $i < $len; $i++)
        {           
            echo "<tr><td>";
            echo $_POST['item'][$i] . '<br>';
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo $_POST['qty'][$i] . '<br>';
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo $_POST['price'][$i] . '<br>';
            echo "</td><td>";
            $tv = ($_POST['qty'][$i]*$_POST['price'][$i]);
            echo $tv;
            echo "</td></tr>";      
$sum += $tv; // with each loop ads new
        }
```

Basics :)

Comment: thanks a ton.you rock.  works perfect. ya it's basics but i am also a complete non programmer. hehe anyways thanks again